# Convert Array of Objects to Multi Dimensional Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I an new to java script and have array of objects as following

```
[{
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: 46
},
{
    firstName: "Mike",
    lastName: "Jeffrey",
    age: 56
}]
```

I would like to convert this array of objects to multi-dimensional array as following

```
[
    [{
        firstName: "John",
        lastName: "Doe",
        age: 46
    }],
    [{
        firstName: "Mike",
        lastName: "Jeffrey",
        age: 56
    }]
]
```

I am using the following code to convert to multi dimension array

```
var actualResult = [];
var arrayLength = inputObj.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
    var tempResult = [];
    tempResult.push(inputObj[i]);
    actualResult.push(tempResult);
}
```

where inpuObj is my actual input.Is this the correct way of achieving the scenario?

Comment: can I ask why do you want to achieve that? You're still going to have to access a dictionary in the `i` position of the first array anyway

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Shinra tensei  I am using a tool where the underlying components uses javascript and this is one of the scenario I want to achieve in order to process data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `array#map`. Iterate through each object and create an array.

```js
var data = [{firstName: "John",lastName: "Doe",age: 46},{firstName: "Mike",lastName: "Jeffrey",age: 56}],
    result = data.map(o => [o]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: what if I get the payload dynamically which is stored in msg variable then is it msg, result =data.map(o=>[o]);?

Comment: You need to make sure that your data is array, in your code it is undefined.